# LINQ Left Outer Join with Group By and Count Producing Error

Tags: linq, join

I'm constructing a LINQ query expression in LINQPad that uses a left outer join, group by and count. The query is producing the following error.

> 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'ContentTypeID'
>   and no extension method 'ContentTypeID' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (press F4 to add a using
>   directive or assembly reference)

Here is the query.

```
from t1 in ContentTypes
from t2 in VwContentTRIGOF.Where(x => t1.ContentTypeID == x.ContentTypeID && new List<int> { 2588, 2227 }.Contains(x.ResearchAreaID)).DefaultIfEmpty()
where t1.IsActive == true
group new {t1, t2} by new { t1.ContentTypeID, t1.Label } into g
select new { g.Key.ContentTypeID, g.Key.Label, Disabled = g.Count(t => t.ContentTypeID == null) > 0 }
```

The error highlights the last use of ContentTypeID in the last line, but I can't seem to arrange the query to get the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item of your group has entries `t1` and `t2`, not `ContentTypeID`, so I suspect your final `select` should be:

```
select new { g.Key.ContentTypeID, g.Key.Label,
             Disabled = g.Count(t => t.t2.ContentTypeID == null) > 0 }
```

(That's assuming you want it from `t2` - if you want it from `t1` then change it appropriately... but given that `t1.ContentTypeID` is part of the key, that seems unlikely... the count would just be the group count.)

Comment: Too fast for StackOverflow. I can't accept your answer for another few minutes. :) Thanks for your help.